# why does the missing function not work inside of reactive RShiny?

Tags: r, function, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I have an R shiny app that filters on some variables and returns a table using modules. I'd like to use `missing()` so that the app will still work even if no value is provided to the module. However, when I use `missing()` inside `reactive()` it gives an error: `Warning: Error in missing: 'missing' can only be used for arguments`. Does anyone know why this might be the case? Is there a way to get around this?

Example app:

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(letters,100,T), b = sample(10,100,T))
dfFilter <- function(data, a, b){
  if (!missing(a)) {
    if(!is.null(a)){
      data <- data[data$a %in% a,]
    }
  }
  if (!missing(b)) {
    if(!is.null(b)){
      data <- data[data$b %in% b,]
    }
  }
  return(data)
}
filterTable <- function(input, output, session, data, aFetcher, bFetcher){
  return(reactive(dfFilter(data = data,
                a = switch(!missing(aFetcher),
                                 aFetcher(),NULL),
                b = switch(!missing(bFetcher),
                                 bFetcher(), NULL))))


}

displayTableUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns('displayer'))
}
displayTable <- function(input, output, session, data){
  output$displayer <- DT::renderDataTable(data())
}


chooserUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('filter'))
}
chooseA <- function(input, output, session, data){
  output$filter <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    pickerInput(inputId = ns('filter'),
                label = 'Choose A:',
                choices = unique(data$a),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = TRUE)
  })

  return(reactive(input$filter))

}
chooseB <- function(input, output, session, data){
  output$filter <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    pickerInput(inputId = ns('filter'),
                label = 'Choose B:',
                choices = unique(data$b),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = TRUE)
  })

  return(reactive(input$filter))

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel('data',
           sidebarPanel(
             chooserUI('aChooser'),
             chooserUI('bChooser')
           ),
           mainPanel(
             displayTableUI('table1')
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  chosenA <- callModule(chooseA,
                        id = 'aChooser',
                        data = df)
  chosenB <- callModule(chooseB,
                        id = 'bChooser',
                        data = df)
  table1 <- callModule(filterTable, 
                       data = df,
                       id = 'tableFilterer',
                       aFetcher = chosenA,
                       bFetcher = chosenB)
  callModule(displayTable, id = 'table1', data = table1)


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I read in the doc of `missing()` "Currently missing can only be used in the immediate body of the function that defines the argument, not in the body of a nested function or a local call" and `reactive()` is nested function of `filterTable()`. IMHO.

Comment: Ah right! That makes sense then as I just found a solution that uses `exists()` instead of `missing()`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using `exists()` instead of `!missing()`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(letters,100,T), b = sample(10,100,T))
dfFilter <- function(data, a, b){
  if (!missing(a)) {
    if(!is.null(a)){
      data <- data[data$a %in% a,]
    }
  }
  if (!missing(b)) {
    if(!is.null(b)){
      data <- data[data$b %in% b,]
    }
  }
  return(data)
}
filterTable <- function(input, output, session, data, aFetcher, bFetcher){
  return(reactive(dfFilter(data = data,
                a = switch(exists(aFetcher),
                                 aFetcher(),NULL),
                b = switch(exists(bFetcher),
                                 bFetcher(), NULL))))


}

displayTableUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns('displayer'))
}
displayTable <- function(input, output, session, data){
  output$displayer <- DT::renderDataTable(data())
}


chooserUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('filter'))
}
chooseA <- function(input, output, session, data){
  output$filter <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    pickerInput(inputId = ns('filter'),
                label = 'Choose A:',
                choices = unique(data$a),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = TRUE)
  })

  return(reactive(input$filter))

}
chooseB <- function(input, output, session, data){
  output$filter <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    pickerInput(inputId = ns('filter'),
                label = 'Choose B:',
                choices = unique(data$b),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = TRUE)
  })

  return(reactive(input$filter))

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel('data',
           sidebarPanel(
             chooserUI('aChooser'),
             chooserUI('bChooser')
           ),
           mainPanel(
             displayTableUI('table1')
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  chosenA <- callModule(chooseA,
                        id = 'aChooser',
                        data = df)
  chosenB <- callModule(chooseB,
                        id = 'bChooser',
                        data = df)
  table1 <- callModule(filterTable, 
                       data = df,
                       id = 'tableFilterer',
                       aFetcher = chosenA,
                       bFetcher = chosenB)
  callModule(displayTable, id = 'table1', data = table1)


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```